# Solr Facet Alpha Numeric sorting with fractions and decimals

Tags: solr

I have records in solr with a field that has numeric values followed by an word.  The numeric values included decimals and fractions.  For example values of this field could be

- 1 1/2 inches
- 11 inches
- 2 inches
- 3/4 inch
- 0.7 inch
- 0.8 inch

Using sort by index in solr, I will get the following order:

- 0.7 inch
- 0.8 inch
- 1 1/2 inches
- 11 inches
- 2 inches
- 3/4 inch

If I use a solution of producing an alphanumeric field from https://www.andornot.com/blog/post/Make-numbers-behave-when-sorting-alphanumerically-in-Solr.aspx
I get the following order:

- 0.7 inch
- 0.8 inch
- 1 1/2 inches
- 2 inches
- 3/4 inch
- 11 inches

The improvement is that Solr Facet recognizes that 11 is greater than 2.  The order I need, however, should be:

- 0.7 inch
- 3/4 inch
- 0.8 inch
- 1 1/2 inches
- 2 inches
- 11 inches

How do I get solr to sort facet values with decimals and fractions alphanumerically?

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is: you don't. Solr is not aware that 3/4 == 0.75.

But it's Solr, so there might be a custom solution to this and it depends on the amount of fractions you've got.

1. When you have only a fixed set of fractions, like standard plumbing sizes or wrench sizes, you could use the [SynonymGraphFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-SynonymGraphFilter) and define the standard fractions to be replaced with their related number e.g. `3/4 => 0.75`. That yields sortability and also adds flexibility on what the search query can contain (i.e. both formats).
2. When synonyms are not helpful, you can of course go the full distance and [write your own Solr filter](https://solr.pl/en/2012/05/14/developing-your-own-solr-filter/). It's actually not that hard and in it you could just split your input string, let Java parse the fraction to a floating point number and write that into the token stream. Yields the same benefits as solution 1.